# How to permanently install python modules?

Tags: python, add-on

I developed a plugin for an artist I work with and that plugin requires a few python modules to work. I figured how to install these modules with PIP. The problem it each time Blender is updated the modules are lost and have to be installed again.

Is there a way to make the installation permanent? For context, the artist is working on Windows.

Comment: Can;t you use a LTS version and simply not update it? This is assuming that Blender 3.3 which is the current LTS version is sufficient. - 3.6 LTS doesn't appear until July.

Comment: On windows you can use symlinks to create a virtual link between two lib folders.